# transform.Translate not working

Tags: unity-game-engine

I added a animation controller to my player and transform.Translate no longer works. The game runs but i cant move the player. I made sure the method was getting called and the script was attached to the player. Any Ideas? I can provide more info if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your AnimatorControlller, uncheck **Apply Root Motion**

Comment: Hmm, if you disable the animation controller, does the translate work again?

Comment: Just to triple check, when the game is playing, the ApplyRootMotion is still checked off? (when the animation controller is enabled)